# PHP adding time

Tags: php, time, addition

I have a code where I have 2 texboxes and a button where it adds the time value of those textboxes according to input.

Here is my simple code:

```
<?php 

echo "<form method=post><input type=text name=etd>";
echo "<input type=text name=btime>";
echo "<input type=submit name=sub value=submit></form>";
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{

        $etime = $_POST['etd'];
        $btym = $_POST['btime'];
        $time = strtotime("$etime");
        $tym = strtotime("btym");
        $etym = strtotime("+$btym hours", $time);
        $eta = date('H:i:s', $etym);

echo "$eta";
}
?>
```

This works however, when I input 12:00 and 00:30 (meaning I want to add 30 minutes to 12:00), it outputs 11:30 which is supposed to be 12:30. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably won't solve your particular problem, but all your html attribute values should be in quotes.  E.g. `<input type="text" name="etd">`

Comment: i'm using echo "<input type=text name=btime>"; so I will get an error if I add double quotes inside it. :))

Comment: Then use single quotes inside it or for your echo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your replies! :))) This is my first post and I feel so glad that you guys answered! :))) Got it working by using mysql addtime() and timediff() function. It worked easily without me banging my head on the table. Thanks anyway for the replies! I'll be on your hands from now on since I think I'll be posting a lot of questions. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this:

```
$tym = strtotime("btym");
```

Be this:

```
$tym = strtotime("$btym");
```

?

Comment: `$tym` is never used in the code - This won't change anything.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense, since `$btwm` is in `$etym = strtotime("+$btym hours", $time);`, and it wouldn't make sense to have a UNIX timestamp within the string `+{SOMETHING} hours`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Although, if you want to use 30 minutes, your value for `btime` should be `0.5`, not `0:30` (since the reference in your `strtotime()` call is to hours).

As the commenter suggested, all your attributes should be wrapped in quotations.

```
<?php 

echo '<form method=post><input type="text" name="etd">';
echo '<input type="text" name="btime">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit"></form>';
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $eta = date('H:i:s', strtotime( $_POST['etd'] . ' +' . $_POST['btime'] . ' hours' ) );
    echo "$eta";
}
?>
```